# A non-numeric value encountered SQL Doctrine

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm

I would like make this request with Doctrine  but when I want try to die & dump my request, a error is return like what my calculation request is not a numeric value. However the value to "poids" and "volumeAdmin" are integer values.

My calculation request:

```
    public function calcPoids(){
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
                   ->join('s.id', 's')
                   ->addSelect('s')
                   ->select((('a.poids * s.volumeAdmin')/100));
        
        return $qb->getQuery()
                 ->getResult(); 
    }
```

My calculation request (SQL):

```sql
SELECT ((a.poids * s.volume_admin)/100) AS calc FROM animal a
JOIN substance s ON s.id = a.substance_id
```

Comment: Hi - are any of the values for "poids" and "volumeAdmin" NULL/empty/0 ?

Comment: "poids" and "volumeAdmin" are not empty but "poids" is nullable=true